# Cannot change itext image border in java

Tags: java, itext

I tried to change the color of itext image border in my java application

Below is the code where i am adding the image to pdf.

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));

image.setAbsolutePosition(48f, 723f);
image.scaleAbsolute(65f, 65f);
image.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX); 
image.setBorderWidth(1);
image.setBorderColor(red);
```

This code is not working. I found that setBorderColor is used for it. But it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown in your code how your image is added to the document. Are you using `itextpdf.text.Document.add` or something else?

Comment: yes i am using Document.add..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iText version 5.5.11 (the development snapshot), this does the trick:

```
//image == string containing path to my .png image file
Image img = Image.getInstance(image);
img.scaleAbsolute(200,200);
img.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
img.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
img.setBorderWidth(1f);

doc.add(img);
```

A thin, red border is drawn around my image. Modifying width and color changes width and color, as expected.

Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: @RameesVP If my answer solves the issue, can you please accept and upvote so that future readers knows which one to use? Still a bit baffled since I basically did the same thing as you originally did. Maybe your color wasn't defined correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 image.setBorderColor(new Color(231,219,80,255));
```

Answer (score 0):

For .Net, Try this Example

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance("..\\..\\test.jpg");
img.ScalePercent(100.0f*72.0f/img.PlainWidth);

img.Border = Rectangle.BOX; 
img.BorderWidth = 3.0f; 
img.BorderColor = Color.RED;
```